# passing a filename as a parameter from a for loop in python flask

Tags: python, for-loop, flask, jinja2

I am uploading file so i am trying to pass a filename after looping through but i am getting an `unbountLocalerror`. i have tried making the filename global so that it can be seen outside the for loop but its throwing filename not defined. what other way can i use to get the filename so i can use it in html/jinja

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():

    target = os.path.join(APP_ROOT,'static/')
    if not os.path.isdir(target):
        os.mkdir(target)
    else:
        for upload in request.files.getlist('file'):
            filename = upload.filename
            destination = "/".join([target, filename])
            upload.save(destination)
    return render_template("upload.html",filename=filename)
```

Comment: It’s not obvious where the error is happening: please edit the _full_ error message into your question.

Answer (score 2):

- The error occurred because you created the local variable inside the `else` statement.
- If, for example the condition was that it triggered the `if:` part
  of the code, the local variable `filename` would never be created.
- Therefore, the `unbound` error occurred when you tried to access it in `return render_template("upload.html",filename=filename)`.
- It also seems that you wanted to return multiple renders - because you don't have just one `filename` but bunch of them.
- I changed the function to return the list of `render_template` objects created based on `filenames` list that is being appended on  line 10 (    `filenames.append(upload.filename)`).

Code:

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():

    target = os.path.join(APP_ROOT,'static/')
    if not os.path.isdir(target): #Create the target folder if it doesnt exitst
        os.mkdir(target)

    filenames = []
    for upload in request.files.getlist('file'): #Upload files into the folder
        filenames.append(upload.filename)
        destination = "/".join([target, upload.filename])
        upload.save(destination)

    return [render_template("upload.html",filename = filename) for filename in filenames] #Return therender_template
```